# Generate a PDF poster in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, poster

I have a requirement to auto generate a poster in PDF format based on a template in. This PDF must contain custom text and images provided via a web application. I know you can add from fields to a PDF then fill them with something like iTextSharp (I'm using C#) but these have solid backgrounds so can't be overlaid onto a poster. I have tried to create a transparent form control in OpenOffice but it does not seem possible. Can anyone suggest a method of fulfilling this requirement?

Many thanks

Comment: Code please. We can't work in a vacuum.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet. I'm just asking for some suggestions on how I may be able to achieve the above.

Comment: Start coding. When stuck, post the code and we will help.

Comment: I can't start writing any code until I know how I'm going to solve the problem. This isn't a coding issue, I'm just asking for some library suggestions.

Comment: Which is considered open-ended and therefore not a good fit for Stack Overflow - read the FAQ.

Comment: I disagree, there is nothing in the FAQ that says you have to post code. My question is: how can I generate a poster in PDF format? I think that is fairly specific and not open ended.

Comment: The question is open-ended. That **is** mentioned in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using ITextsharp.Its a very powerful PDF library. Keep the background as a pdf and load it in a stream. Then you can write on the loaded pdf and can return the poster.

```
 private PdfContentByte _pcb; 
Document document = new Document();

FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
PdfReader Mypdfreader= new PdfReader(fileStream);
 PdfTemplate background = writer.GetImportedPage(Mypdfreader, 1);
 document.NewPage();
_pcb = writer.DirectContentUnder;
_pcb.AddTemplate(background, 0, 0);
 _pcb = writer.DirectContent;
_pcb.BeginText();
         _pcb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false), 10);
 _pcb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, text, 10, 5, 0);//10,5 are x and y coordinates resp.
 _pcb.EndText();

 writer.Flush();
fileStream.Close();
```

or refer to the sample
[PDF poster](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277065/Creating-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp)